# Loop for era suposto a ser executado 5 vezes, mas é executado apenas 1

Tags: loop, for, lua

Então, eu estou tendo um problema com um loop `for` no código a seguir:

```
for i=1,#collisionBlocks do
    t=collisionBlocks[i]
    print(#collisionBlocks)
    print(i)
    if player.y-1<t[4] and player.y-1>t[2] and ((player.x>=t[1] and player.x<=t[3]) or (player.x+50>=t[1] and player.x<=t[3])) then print'nao da para andar pra cima' return false end
    return true
end
```

A tabela `collisionBlocks` possui 5 outras tabelas dentro, mas o loop é executado apenas uma vez, sendo que ele era para ser executado 5 vezes já que a tabela `collisionBlocks` possui 5 itens dentro dela. Tanto que se você executar a função que executa esse loop, vai aparecer:

```
>5
>1
```

sendo que deveria aparecer:

```
>5
>1
>5
>2
>5
>3
>5
>4
>5
>5
```

Comment: O que são os `return` dentro do laço? Isso pertence a uma função? Se sim, o `return` sempre irá finalizar a função, independente se há mais iterações no loop.

Comment: Ah, ja sei o que está causando isso. O `return true` no final do loop era para estar fora do loop, logo depois dele terminar. Muito obrigado!

Comment: O programa vai sair do `for` quando encontrar qualquer `return`. Você tem que pensar em uma forma de fazer isso sem usar o `return`.